# While true vs. while (idx+count) < arr.size

Tags: ruby, arrays, while-loop

I'm learning Ruby and am having an issue with this problem:

Prompt :Using the Ruby language, have the function ArrayAdditionI (arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise return the string false. For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers.

My answer is as follows:

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
  largest_num = nil
  arr.each do |element|
    if largest_num == nil || element > largest_num
      largest_num = element
    end
  end

arr = arr - [largest_num]
idx=0
count = 1

while (idx+count) < arr.size # <==== this line
    puts idx+count
    puts arr.size
    count = 1
    result = arr[idx]
    while idx + count < arr.size
        if result + arr[idx+count] == largest_num
            return true
        else
            result = result + arr[idx+count]    
        count+=1
        end
    end
    idx+=1
end
false
end
```

The code doesn't return the right output `true` for `[3,5,-1,8,12]` unless I change the line `while (idx+count) < arr.size` to `while true`. Otherwise, my code in that "while" loop won't loop. Can anyone explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Line 2-6 can be replaced by `largest_num = arr.max`

Answer (score 0):

`count` is reset back to 1 inside the loop, but the outer while loop is checking the condition before it's reset so it will always be false after the first iteration.

If you want the old condition to work, you can move `count = 1` after the line `idx+=1`.

Some other inputs will still return the wrong answer though because you're not checking every combination, only the numbers that are next to each other in the array.